# setting UICollectionViewCell to fit CollectionView

Tags: ios

I'm trying to display pictures in a collection view, 1 picture at a time and allow them to be scrolled horizontally.

so i was hoping to have the cell fit the size of the collection view, perhaps with a bit of margin.

I've tried to do it by setting the cell frame to the same as the collection view's frame

```
CGRect containerFrame =  self.photoCollectionView.frame;
cell.frame = CGRectMake(containerFrame.origin.x, containerFrame.origin.y, containerFrame.size.width, containerFrame.size.height);
```

but the cell just disappears all together.
Is there a standard way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [UICollectionViewFlowLayout Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionViewFlowLayout/itemSize). You should use  `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.

Implement this method to change the size of cells

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and to change the spacing between cells

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
```